# adding new root object to dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary, root

Suggest I've a dictionary looking like this:

```
{'airplane': {}, 'car': {}, 'boat': {}}
```

And I want to add a new root object, making it a dictionary looking like this.

```
{'transportation': {'airplane': {}, 'car': {}, 'boat': {}}}
```

How can this be be achieved?
I'm using a JSON library to manipulate the data.

Regards

Comment: What is the code you are using right now? What library? Typically, you could just create a new JSON object with the key you want and the value will be your older JSON object.

Comment: I'm using a JSON library with existing JSON object. And I want to add a new object, but this new object should be the root object.

Comment: Almost each programming language has a  JSON library nowdays. What language are you using and what code have you tried so far?